# strange (?) behaviour with PHP DateTime object

Tags: php

I am trying to run the following

```
$d = "2015-Mar-22";
$dsd = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-M-d H:i:s', $d . " 00:00:00");
$ds = strtotime($dsd->date);
```

and get

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: DateTime::$date in php shell code on line 1
```

However, if I call `var_dump($dsd)` before converting to a unix timestamp I get the correct answer:

```
echo strtotime($dsd->date);
```

1427007600

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What do you want to change from  `2015-Mar-22` ?

Comment: I have an app that has user select from a list of dates (no times) and I use the selection to define a range of unix timestamps from start to end of day.

Comment: You want to convert it to unix timestamp from the above date ?

Comment: I want the start of day unix timestamp and the end of day unix timestamp.

Comment: Yes. Will update you in few min

Comment: php > $d = "2015-Mar-22";
php > $date = new DateTime($d." 00:00:00");
php > $date2 = new DateTime($d." 23:59:59");
php > strtotime($date->date);
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: DateTime::$date in php shell code on line 1
php > var_dump($date);
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2015-03-22 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(19) "America/Los_Angeles"
}
php > strtotime($date->date);  Gives me correct result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to use an undocumented property that is only ever made available due to [a side effect.](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49382)

> ->date being available is actually a side-effect of support for var_dump()

---

If you just want a timestamp use [`$dsd->getTimestamp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) instead of `strtotime($dsd->date)`.